# AJAX Cross Orign Request or Converting returned Data JSONP to JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, cross-domain

I want to get some JSON data from an URL. I did it successfully with PHP and Guzzle, but my site needs some loading time that's why I want to try the data with AJAX. When I try to get the data with an AJAX-Call, this will happen:

> CORS-Header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing

I googled it and tried things out like adding this header in htaccess and htttp.conf and so on. Nothing changed, always getting this error message.

When I tried to retrieve the data as JSONP, I get the message:

> Missing ; before Statement

Googled it too, my question is, is there maybe a way to convert JSON to JSONP while I am getting it via AJAX? Or did someone has another idea to solve the cross origin problem?

EDIT:
Data I want to get: https://www.easports.com/fifa/api/fifa16-ps4/stats/fut/Haggelodeon (maybe you need to hit the url twice to get data)

Ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
 url: "https://www.easports.com/fifa/api/fifa16-ps4/stats/fut/Haggelodeon?callback=?",
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
 }
 });
```

I believe this is the code I tried, I deleted it in the meantime so there could be a mistake, especially with the url, I don't know if the callback-part is right from my memory.

Comment: Do you have control of the domain you are making the request to? If not, there is nothing you can do. The first error means that the URL does not accept CORS requests. The second error means they do not return data in JSONP format. Because of this any attempt you make to retrieve data through AJAX will be blocked by the Same Origin Policy. Your original method of making the request server-side is the only way that will work reliably for this particular domain.

Comment: No I have not control of it :( Thought it would be a better solution for me, but thanks for your help ;)

Comment: You may want to post some of your code that attempts to retrieve the data as JSONP. The error message there sounds like some sort of syntax error being hit.

Comment: The data is not JSONP, the end point needs to server it up as JSONP and if the site does not set the CORS header on their end you can not do anything about it.